# my green giant arbovitae are suffering

Tags: shrubs, evergreens

I got 30 green giant arbovitae planted in my backyard as a natural fence about a month and a half ago (I live in Massachusetts, near the cost).
I have been giving then water for ~25 seconds from the hose, daily.
Some look good but most, started to develop brown color in their tips and one looks too bad...
Is there any obvious step that i could take to save them? Any less obvious?
These are some images of the trees.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These plants have dried out.  Twenty five seconds of water is not near enough.  Your soil and the amount of mulch will affect how well water is retained but in general you need to water the root ball, not around it, for as long as it takes to soak the entire root ball.

This should continue for at least at week after planting possibly more if the weather is hot and dry.

Comment: There is no way to recover them?

Comment: if I water them properly (those whose tips are brown), will they bounce back in your opinion? Thank you!

Comment: @aerijman the brown parts are dead and will never come back.  But...arborvitae are vigorous growers.  Water more, replace the worst looking one and in a few years the new growth will hide the older parts

Comment: that was helpful. thank you. !